# How can I prevent water from leaking on an outlet?

Tags: electrical, plumbing, clothes-washer

I recently moved into a new house rental and am setting up my washer & dryer. I am uncomfortable with the proximity of our hot/cold water valves to our washer's power outlet and was wondering if anyone has any suggestions to prevent water leakage onto the outlet (perhaps an outlet cover or valve cover would help?). Please see the attached image. Thanks for you help. -Jared

[image: Outlet, water valves, and drain pipe.]

Comment: This would be an instant fail in any building inspection in my country.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way to prevent water issues would be to move the outlet and/or valves. If that is not preferable, at least ensure that the outlet is protected by a GFI, or install a GFI receptacle at that location. You could also use a weatherproof "in-use" cover. Keep a close eye on your hoses and valves and repair at first sign of leak. Turn those faucets off when you go on vacation.

[image]

Comment: We were able to get our landlord to move the water valves slightly to the right and add a GFI. We never need the hot water and keep the cold off when it is not in use. I wish we could move the outlet to the adjacent wall, but that wasn't a possibility. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternative possibilities would be:

- Build a separate (waterproof) vertical conduit to contain and isolate the water system - both incoming pipes and what looks to be a drain on the right of the image. This would not need to be very large, perhaps 1 foot square could be enough.
- Move the water valves down as low as possible. The rationale being that the electrical cable leading up to the outlets seems to be in good condition and, one hopes, water resistant - while the outlets are not. If there is a spill, better it affects just the cable and not the receptacle. It is also easier to shorten water tubing than to extend electrical wiring (while maintaining waterproofing across joints).

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways, but the best is, imho, **moving the outlet somewhere else**. Of course - You can use 'waterproof' boxes (not the best look if You ask me), You can move the pipes, which is unconvenient and risky. Moving this outlet to the left (there is a wall on the left, am I right?), using either same cable or making it longer - Your choice.
Definitely - leaving it as it is now is very risky, and dangerous.

Comment: @mjohns615 Of course, You are right. It was because of my misunderstanding. I just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to tighten the valves so much that it won’t leak. Make sure the nut is also fixed properly. It depends on how frequently you will open the valve. If it is too frequent it’s better you change the place of the switches or relocate the valves.